# Why a fragment View does not change on app android?

Tags: android

I have a navigation Drawer which implement 2 fragments Header & Footer. I try to set some data to the Header Fragment in it `onCreateView` function but the fragment does not change after the loading in the navigation Drawer

**The `onCreateView`of the HeaderFragement**

```
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, container, false);

     name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameH);
     img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);

     name.setText(infos.getString("Name"));
     img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(infos.getString("ImgUrl")));


     return v;

}
```

**And this is how i implement them into the NavigationDrawer  :**

```
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);
    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);


    mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Any help please Thanks

Comment: Can't see a fragment...you are adding views, not fragments.

Comment: Yes and in the onCreateView in modify them but why i can see the change ?

Comment: You can't! Your onCreateView is probably correct, but you don't add the fragment anywhere, you are adding a View. To add a fragment, check out FragmentManager and Fragment Transactions.